# Hide some text when word prints

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2007

I created a template in MS word that has our letterhead layout on it which is great if we're printing to PDF or just holding onto the document.  However, if we're printing to actual paper, we'd like to print it on our professionally printed letterhead.  The trouble is, we can't just print my letterhead over the Printer's letterhead because then it looks like crap.

So, is there some way to tell word that some text shouldn't be printed?  (bonus if I can specify which printer gets this treatment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the heading hidden text and then either toggle "Print hidden text" in Word Options|Display|Printing Options or use styles to toggle whether the heading is hidden or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could make text color white for any text you want to hide.

Or, you could just use 2 different templates, and use one with the extra text, and one without. To follow on from that, uou could make 2 ms word icons. One starts word with one template, one starts word with the other template.  Here is a webpage on word startup switches
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565

Ideal may be a macro to toggle whether letterhead or not, and set the correct printer and possibly print too. But I don't know how you'd go about that.